# Atomatic login to webpage by copying username password from excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple script to login to the webpage but now I have a requirement to build a VB script where if I click a button

1. it should login to the webpage
2. Copy paste username & password from excel sheet to webpage
3. then click Login button to login to the webpage

Comment: Can you pls share your script to look it in further...

Comment: Hi Apurv, the script I have is simple one to login to the website with user name password provided in the script iteself. What is need now is a script which can login to the webpage by Copying username & password from excel sheet.

Comment: Function Main
  Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "http://10.195.98.10/"
  Wait IE
  With IE.Document
    .getElementByID("Userid").value = "username"
    .getElementByID("Password").value = "password"  End With
End Function
Sub Wait(IE)
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
End Sub
Sub IE_OnQuit
  On Error Resume Next
  WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "IE closed before script finished."
  WScript.Quit
  End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Simlply enter the location of the username and password in the script.

like below
 .getelementbyid("userid").value =range("a1").value
similarly for pw.
.getelementbyid("Password").value =range("a2").value

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this.

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

' Get username and password from worksheet.  Not very secure, but this way the credentials are always sitting in the same spot and the user doesn't have to enter these each time.
' Alternative is to use an input box toprompt the user for crednetials.
UserName = Worksheets("ControlSheet").Range("A1").Value
Password = Worksheets("ControlSheet").Range("A2").Value

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "YOUR_1ST_URL_HERE"

' Wait for the page to fully load; you can't do anything if the page is not fully loaded
Do While .Busy Or _
    .readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

On Error Resume Next
'Credentials are passed to the site and the button is clicked (by the code).
ie.document.forms(0).all("username").Value = UserName
ie.document.forms(0).all("password").Value = Password
ie.document.forms(0).submit.Click

    ' Wait for the page to fully load; you can't do anything if the page is not fully loaded
    Do While .Busy Or _
        .readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    .navigate "YOUR_2ND_URL_HERE"

    Do While .Busy Or _
        .readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
```